# How to read a Harwell-Boeing Matrix file format into a compressed sparse row format in a C program?

Tags: matrix

I have to write a program where I have to perform matrix-vector multiplication and the matrix is sparse matrix. Most sparse matrices available online are in Harwell-Boeing format and they have to be read in compressed sparse row format in order to do operations on it. How should I read such a file and convert into compressed sparse row format in a C programming framework?

Comment: The format appears to be described here: http://math.nist.gov/MatrixMarket/formats.html#hb

Answer (score 4):

Tim Davis' SuiteSparse package has a function for reading matrices in that
format:
http://faculty.cse.tamu.edu/davis/suitesparse.html
It appears that you have to download the entire SuiteSparse package but if all
you want is to read Harwell-Boeing files, you really need only one routine
from that package: RBio/Source/RBio.c. Note, you will also need a couple of
include files that are also part of the package in order to compile that function.

Comment: Thanks for the information Bill Greene. After following your link I also found another link http://bebop.cs.berkeley.edu/smc/ . Infact both were helpful.